# Prove that the function $f^2+f^3$ attains every complex value.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is a nonconstant entire function, prove that the range of $f^2+f^3$ is the entire complex plane.

I tried to solve the exercise by using the Little Picard's theorem. Specifically, i assumed that $\exists w_0 : f^2(z)+f^3(z) \neq w_0, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$, and using this assumption to show somehow that $f$ ommits two complex values, hence it is constant. However i can't find any way to show it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p\colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ denote the polynomial $p(z) = z^3 + z^2$. As $f$ is entire and non-constant, by Little picard, $f$ attains all values of $\mathbb C$, with exemption of at most one, say $z_0$.

Now let $w_0 \in \mathbb C$ be arbitrary, as $p(z) - w_0$ is a nonconstant polynomial which is no third power (and hence cannot have a triple zero at one point), there at least two points $z_1, z_2$ with $p(z_1) = p(z_2) = w_0$. Now at least one of the $z_i$, say $z_1$ has $z_i \ne z_0$. So there is a $q \in \mathbb C$ with $f(q) = z_1$, so $$(f^3 + f^2)(q) = p\circ f(q) = p(z_1) = w_0. $$

Comment: Perfect solution thank you very much!